# Combining Javascript commands into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code for validating letter input into input boxes in a form. The following code works perfectly, but I have two (possibly more) boxes I need to validate to disallow letters being input into them.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtTables").keydown(function (e) {
               if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 190]) !== -1 ||
                    (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                    (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                    return;
                }
                if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });
```

Works fine, but I also have #txtIndividuals that I need validated.. so at the moment, I have this piece of code directly below the above block...

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtIndividuals").keydown(function (e) {
               if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 190]) !== -1 ||
                    (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                    (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                    // let it happen, don't do anything
                    return;
                }
                if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });
```

Can I group these together? If so, how? Any help with this is appreciated :) thanks!

Comment: http://bit.ly/1bOaj3E

Comment: you can add a validate_letters class to your code and add this class to where ever you want to apply validation same replace the id in your selector with that class

Comment: @VovaLando - I actually didn't know it was referred to as a 'selector', and if you google 'Javascript group commands' which is what I was looking at, nothing comes up which is why I posted here. No need to be a prick about the fact you found the answer in double-quick time. It's always easier when you know exactly what you're looking for! Tibos answered me quickly and concisely, which is what I was looking for. It's people like you who make people NOT want to ask for help. Your answer was not needed.

Comment: @CJPayne, dude, don't be so sensitive, I didn't saw Tibos answer when I put my comment, and my comment just answers your question, and also guides you to use search engines and jQuery API to find answers before you ask community. And that what I believe is a good practice. But whatever. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by [grouping](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#grouping) the two selectors into one:

```
$("#txtTables, #txtIndividuals").keydown( ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="text"]').keydown( ... );

$("#txtTables, #txtIndividuals").keydown( ... );
```

Comment: Hi, You dun't need to set input filed's id in the code, it will be good for all the input fields on your page. Now you dun't need to set id for each input field, It will automatically picks all the input fields and apply validation on them.

Comment: It's a form, so all the other fields have their own sort of validation on them, I just needed the numbered fields to disallow text input. Thanks anyways!

Comment: no problem, then you can use $("#txtTables, #txtIndividuals").keydown( ... );